# Need to make a buffer around a part of a feature, keeping other features attached

Tags: buffer

Basic problem:
I have two layers, a layer containing river basin outlines and a layer of wetland outlines and types.

I need to make a buffer around one river basin, and then create 100 random points within a single type of wetlnad within the river basin + buffer.

I guess the first problem is how to create a buffer around just one river basin when the layer contains many (they do not overlap). The second problem is that I need to isolate just one wetland type within the total area contained by the buffer (so that river basin + the buffer around it), so that I can make random points inside that wetland type.

I've been fighting with trying to make a buffer around just that one river basin for days, I'm sure it's possible but I've never used buffers before. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

- Blue

Comment: What GIS software do you have access to?

Answer (score 4):

For an ArcGIS solution, you can accomplish this analysis with a combination of selections, an intersect and via the create random points tool.

- Use a select tool to identify your basin.  Make sure it is highlighted (usually in light blue)

[image]

- Run the [Buffer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000) tool on the "selected" river basin layer.  To combine the buffer and the selected feature, use [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) and [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000), as required.  Make sure the basin is still selected.
- Perform a SQL search to select the particular wetlands you want.  A
  query similar to "wetlands" = 'riparian' should be added to the
  [Select by Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000021000000) search.

[image]

- Add the buffered riparian basin and the selected wetlands layer to
  the [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool.
- Now you have a polygon that represents the particular area you are
  interested in based on two layers.
- Use the [Create Random Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002r000000) tool.  Make sure to use the
  intersected polygon as your *constraining featureclass*--this will
  allow points to be randomly generated only within the polygon.